# How to deal with type name conflicts in a typescript definition file

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

I'm trying to write a typescript definition file for an already existing library.  This library ([react-filepond](https://github.com/pqina/react-filepond)) exports an object called `File` (as can be seen in the [usage example in the README](https://github.com/pqina/react-filepond)).

The problem with that is that another one of the interfaces that this library creates utilizes the [JS File interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).

So now in my typescript definition file I have to somehow manage two definitions of the type `File`.  My solution to this was to declare the object that the library creates as a different name in my definition file, and simply export it as "File".

```
declare class FilePondFile extends React.Component<FilePondFileProps> { }
export { FilePondFile as File };
```

That seems fine and dandy when I use the type in my own project.  But as a proponent of OSS, I want to make this definition available to the community via the [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) repo.

Their linter give me an error though that is apparently preventing [my PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/31362) from being reviewed:

```
Error: C:/dev/DefinitelyTyped/types/react-filepond/index.d.ts:22:1
ERROR: 22:1   strict-export-declare-modifiers  'declare' keyword is redundant here. 
See: https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint/blob/master/docs/strict-export-declare-modifiers.md
```

At first glance it seems simple enough to remove the `declare` that is in front of `class FilePondFile`, however, if I remove it, I get a different error:

```
A 'declare' modifier is required for a top level declaration in a .d.ts file.
```

So I'm not sure how to handle this contradiction.  The maintainers of Definitely Typed don't seem to have time to assist as my PR was just labeled "Needs Author Attention", despite my clear laying out of this problem.

Does anyone have a suggestion of what I can do to not duplicate the reference to `File` in this definition file, while also passing the Definitely Typed linter?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve seems to be impossible with current dtslint rules, you might try to file an issue in [dtslint repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint)

Comment: Good idea, thank you!  I've done so [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint/issues/173).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem with that is that another one of the interfaces that this
>   library creates utilizes the JS File interface.

There is another solution.

The `File` name is taken by the class that's declared and exported from this module.

You have to describe `FilePondItem` interface in the same module, and it must have `file` property with `File` type which is different - it must refer to a global `File` object which is defined in lib.dom.d.ts

```
export interface FilePondItem {
    file: File;
```

TypeScript types are structural. You don't have to refer to global `File` type by name, you can provide its definition, compatible with the one in [lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5110):

```
export interface FilePondItem {
    file: Blob & {readonly lastModified: number; readonly name: string};
```

and everything will be just fine as long as type definitions will remain compatible.

There are drawbacks, of course: it's a duplicate code, it's more verbose, and there is a risk that it will become incompatible with actual `File` in the future if global `File` type changes (however I think that's unlikely).

Comment: That's a great idea, thank you!  Unfortunately after adpoting Karol's [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53878370/1), making the linting errors go away, my pull request was merged just a few minutes before you posted this answer.  I will make a modification in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

This error message:

> A 'declare' modifier is required for a top level declaration in a
>   .d.ts file.

is displayed when a declaration file doesn't export anything. The `declare` keyword is redundant because it's assumed in `*.d.ts` files already.

The purpose of having declaration files is describing exactly what's going on in the corresponding JavaScript module. [At the time of writing this post](https://github.com/pqina/react-filepond/blob/62169c7050fc0b5f1264f1720ea08da94a3fb112/lib/index.js), `react-filepond` contains 3 named exports: `const registerPlugin`, `class FilePond`, and `class File`. This means your declaration could look like this:

**`types/react-filepond/index.d.ts`**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { registerPlugin } from 'filepond';

export { registerPlugin };

interface Props { /* FilePond props here */ }

export class FilePond extends React.Component<Props> { }

export class File extends React.Component { }
```

because that's what's really happening in the module. Note: if typings for `filepond` are not there, it may be a good idea to start by creating types for that library first.

If a consumer runs into naming conflicts, it's their role to provide an alias locally:

```
import { File as FileComponent } from 'react-filepond';
```

Since everyone can have a different setup, running into conflicts is something you (as the typings author) cannot prevent. It's a good practice for library authors to avoid names like that, but if they don't, the type definitions should respect their choice.

Comment: But this is misleading because this javascript library does not export anything named `FilePondFile` - anyone trying to use that name will get `ReferenceError: Cannot find variable: FilePondFile` at runtime.

Comment: You're correct, that's an overlooking. I updated the answer.

Comment: KarolMajewski I was prepared to mark your original answer as correct, but I believe that your updated answer no longer solves the problem of avoiding the name conflict.  @artem has a very valid point that exporting both is misleading, but for the time being I believe that having a slightly misleading type definition is preferable to not having one at all.  If you restore your original answer I will re-mark it!

Comment: Thank you, but that wouldn't be fair — the purpose of declaration files is to describe precisely what's going on in the corresponding JavaScript module. In this case, the module has 3 named exports: `const registerPlugin`, `class FilePond`, and `class File`. Since they are named exports, you need to preserve their names, otherwise, the library consumers can run into problems. If there is a conflict, it's the consumer's role to provide an alias in order to prevent it (`import { File as FileComponent } from 'react-filepond';`).